# A delphi code parser that can re-output the delphi source code?

Tags: delphi, parsing, code-formatting

I am trying to do some source-level modifications for delphi source code
(I am working with older delphi6 source code but i am interested in any general feedback).
My direction is to parse the delphi tree, make additions/modifications to the AST or virtual nodes of the parsers, and re-output the code

The the Castalia code parser is nice
https://github.com/jacobthurman/Castalia-Delphi-Parser
But currently there is no code to regenerate the original source code from the parser tree

As a fallback i can output the source code in each virtual node but there is a more complete library?!

I have seen references to the Jedi Code Formatter which could really do the trick
But does the JCF offer the same easy access to each node in the AST where i can make modifications ?!

Thanks all

Comment: Normally you use a parser to convert the source code into another form or to learn information about the structure of the code, which is why the Castalia parser is one-way. But have you tried implementing its methods, in order to output Delphi code as text? What problems did you encounter doing so?

Comment: @DavidM This is what i am trying to do - but there are 200 callbacks and various end-cases which are not easy to test. Any code beautifier knows to re-generate the source code so i would rather start from that.

Comment: I don't know about the Castalia parser, but I have written a number of script parsers and don't follow your problem.  Once you have the parse tree, usually you can just walk the tree and do what you like with each node.  To regenerate the source, I just output the source (code) of each leaf node.  Is that not possible with the Castalia one?

Comment: @user3747518 GExperts has a code formatter - maybe try with that?

Comment: It's very easy to walk the Castalia token tree and output the source again.
I've used it to remove unwanted comment blocks from my code, as well as to regenerate the "uses" section of a DPR in MonkeyMixer (the source for which is on GitHub if you want to see how I do it)

Comment: @LaKraven Absolutely yes.. can u attach a github link ?  If you reply as an answer i will "select" it.

Comment: @user you can use websearch